# Create a real-time line chart by using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create a chart that displays sensor data from a cell phone in real time. I wrote a code for this, but the data was recorded, but the graph was recorded only on the same x-axis. The code is shown below. How should I solve this? If I need to create a separate thread, where should I add it?

```
package com.example.ex_linear_acc_graph

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale
import kotlin.concurrent.timer

class linearActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {

    private val mSensorManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    }

    private lateinit var chart: LineChart
    private lateinit var data: LineData


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linear)


        chart = findViewById(R.id.chart_line)
        chart.description.isEnabled = false
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true)
        chart.isDragEnabled = true
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true)
        chart.setPinchZoom(false)
        chart.legend.form = Legend.LegendForm.LINE
        chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        chart.xAxis.setDrawLabels(true)
        chart.xAxis.axisMaximum = 0f
        chart.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true)
        chart.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        chart.legend.textColor = Color.WHITE
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000)
        chart.invalidate()

        data = LineData()
        chart.data = data
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

       
       

        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)?.also{
                linearacceleration -> mSensorManager.registerListener(
            this,
            linearacceleration,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI
        )}
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {

        var second : Float = 0f

        timer(period = 1000, initialDelay = 1000){
            second++
        }

        if(event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
            val mag_x = event.values[0]
            val mag_y = event.values[1]
            val mag_z = event.values[2]


            val tv_mag : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_linear_acc)
            tv_mag.text = "mag_x : ${mag_x}\nmag_y : ${mag_y}\nmag_z : ${mag_z}"

            val dataSet = LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(second, mag_x), Entry(second, mag_y), Entry(second, mag_z)), "Accelerometer Data")
            data.addDataSet(dataSet)
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // Do nothing
    }





}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - you should make a minimum complete example using pseudo-data that someone else can run and describe better what the issue is that you are facing.

Comment: [Check this, gentleman.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-line-graph-view-with-kotlin/)

Comment: Consider calling `invalidate` after insering new data.